# Prove that: $f(n-1)f(n+1)\le [f(n)]^2$? for all $n$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, induction, cardinals

$k\in\Bbb N$, for each $n\in \Bbb N$ we let $f(n)$ be the number of solutions $(x_1,\cdots,x_k)\in \Bbb Z^k$ of the inequality $$|x_1|+\cdots +|x_k|\le n$$
that is $$f(n)= card\left(\{ (x_1,\cdots,x_k)\in \Bbb Z^k: |x_1|+\cdots +|x_k|\le n\}\right)$$
Then prove that: $$f(n-1)f(n+1)\le [f(n)]^2$$

My intention is to compute first, $$g(n)=  card\left(\{ (x_1,\cdots,x_k)\in \Bbb Z^k: |x_1|+\cdots +|x_k|= n\}\right)$$

since, $$\color{red}{f(n) = f(n-1)+g(n)}$$

But I am wondering whether 
$$\color{red}{g(n)=  2*card\left(\{ (x_1,\cdots,x_k)\in \Bbb N^k: x_1+\cdots +x_k= n\}\right)}$$

I have tried to use the induction I couldn't succeed.

Comment: In addition to considering $g(n) = f(n) - f(n-1)$, perhaps it would also help to consider the ratio $q(n) = f(n) / f(n-1)$. Then the goal is to show $q(n+1)\leq q(n)$.

Comment: $f(n)=\binom {n+k}{k}.$

Comment: how do I obtain that

Comment: Sounds like a [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem and I think $g(n)=2^k \cdot card(...)$ since each $x_i$ can be positive and negative.